# Django: Making an efficient query by removing 340 duplicate queries

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I'm graphing a bunch of price data by day. Think stock trades by day.

**What I want to do:**

- Show the trades by day
- Show the mean line of the prices to show a general trend

**Problem:**

When I look in Django Debug Toolbar at the queries, I see:

- 346 queries
- 1498.11ms
- Looking at the actual queries, I see "Duplicated 340 times" for get_queryset() as it queries each day.
- How can I make this more efficient so there aren't duplicates? Any tips/tricks on how to make this as efficient as possible would be greatly appreciated.

**How:**

I have a view that inherits from a GraphView I've made to return the data necessary to graph the prices of the objects returned. With this request returning potentially thousands of results, getting this query as efficient as possible is important for the load times.

**Tools used:**

- Django 1.10.1
- Postgres
- Plotly to graph the results in the template
- Django debug toolbar

**Views & query:**

```
class GraphView(TemplateView):

    def get_dates(self):
        dates = []
        if self.get_queryset():
            start = self.get_queryset()[0][2].date()
            end = datetime.today().date()
            delta = end - start
            for i in range(delta.days + 1):
                dates.append(start + timedelta(days=i))
        return dates

    def trend_line(self):
        trades = self.get_queryset()
        dates = self.get_dates()
        data_x = []
        data_y = []

        for date in dates:
            subset = trades.filter(date_of_price__date=date)
            prices_for_day = subset.aggregate(Avg('price'))
            if prices_for_day['price__avg'] > 0:
                data_x.append(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
                data_y.append(prices_for_day['price__avg'])
        return data_x, data_y

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GraphView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        x_axis_date = []
        y_axis_price = []
        bubble_text = []
        for trade in self.get_queryset():
            x_axis_date.append(trade[2].date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            y_axis_price.append(int(trade[1]))
            desc = "#%s" % (trade[0])
            bubble_text.append(str(desc.encode('ascii', 'ignore')))

        trend_data_x, trend_data_y = self.trend_line()

        try:
            x_axis_date_start = x_axis_date[0]
        except IndexError:
            x_axis_date_start = None

        try:
            x_axis_date_end = x_axis_date[-1]
        except IndexError:
            x_axis_date_end = None

        context.update({
            "x_axis_date": x_axis_date,
            "x_axis_date_start": x_axis_date_start,
            "x_axis_date_end": x_axis_date_end,
            "y_axis_price": y_axis_price,
            "bubble_text": bubble_text,
            "trend_data_x": trend_data_x,
            "trend_data_y": trend_data_y,
        })
        return context


 class ReferenceDetailView(StaffuserRequiredMixin, SetHeadlineMixin, GraphView):
        headline = "Variation Detail"
        template_name = "ref_trades/reference_detail.html"

        def get_reference_model(self):
            return get_object_or_404(ReferenceModel, pk=self.kwargs["pk"])

        def get_headline(self):
            return "%s" % self.get_reference_model()

        def get_queryset(self):
            return TradeModel.objects.filter(
                date_of_price__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365),
                reference_model__id=self.kwargs["pk"]
            ).exclude(price=0).values_list('id', 'price' , 'date_of_price', 'title')
```

**Thank you**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you use caching?

Comment: Not locally for dev

Comment: Then that is more likely to be an issue that DDT is picking up on, you might want to at least turn on `LocMemCache` for dev. The only other iffy point would be the queries in the for loop in `data_points`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than performing a query per day, you can retrieve all objects ordered by date and then use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to split them into dates.

```
def data_points(self):
    trades = self.get_queryset()
    data_x = []
    data_y = []

    for date, subset in itertools.groupby(trades, lambda t: t.date):
        average_price = average(subset) # average() needs to be implemented
        if average_price > 0:
            data_x.append(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            data_y.append(average_price)
    return data_x, data_y
```

This approach trades web server CPU for DB CPU/IO, this may or may not be the best approach depending on your infrastructure

Comment: Thank Iain, groupby helped tremendously. The results: 5 queries in 22ms! Thanks again, greatly appreciate it!